# Proper way to design an adapter class for two existing class instances?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, adapter, encapsulation

Say, I have a adapter class `ManYouCanHit` for two classes `RichMan` and `TaxiDriver`, both which derive from `Person`. And I can only access the instance of `RichMan` or `TaxiDriver`

```
public interface IManYouCanHit
{
    bool CanIHitThisGuy;
}

public class ManYouCanHit : IManYouCanHit
{
    private enum ManType
    {
        Rich = 0,
        TaxiDriver = 1
    }

    private RichMan richMan;
    private TaxiDriver driver;
    private ManType type;

    public Object ManReference
    {
        get
        {
            if(this.type == ManType.Rich)
            {
                return this.richMan;
            }
            else
            {
                return this.driver;
            }
        }
    }

    public bool CanIHitThisGuy
    {
        get{
            bool canHit = true;
            if(this.type == ManType.RichMan)
            {
                canHit = false;
            }
            return canHit;
        }
    }

    public ManYouCanHit(Person someone)
    {
        if(someone is RichMan)
        {
            this.richMan = someone;
            this.type = ManType.Rich;
        }
        else if(someone is TaxiDriver)
        {
            this.driver = someone;
            this.type = ManType.TaxiDriver;
        }
        else
        {
            // throw an error
        }
    }
}
```

The real logic is complicated than the example, there are many properties and methods to implement like `CanIHitThisGuy`

Is it OK to wrap two object into one adapter? What other pattern can I follow?

Is this design good or bad? Could you please give me some advice?

Should I expose the original object via `ManReference`?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it OK to wrap two object into one adaptor?

Yes you can if you meant two types of object. Not in the way you have done. You're not using OO to good benefit.

> What else pattern can I follow?

Adapter pattern is cool and you should make use of it if it makes sense. But if there's something better is something only you can decide now given the information you have provided.

> Is this design good or bad?

Bad.

> Should I expose the original object via ManReference?

Only you know. Make it immutable if you worry.

> Could you please give me some advice?

I would rewrite it this way:

```
public interface IManYouCanHit
{
    bool CanIHitThisGuy;
}

public class ManYouCanHit : IManYouCanHit
{
    public ManYouCanHit(Person someone)
    {
        if (!(someone is RichMan) && !(someone is TaxiDriver))
            throw;

        Man = someone;
    }

    public Person Man { get; private set; }

    public bool CanIHitThisGuy
    {
        get
        {
           //this is not good, better to have IsHittable property on Person class
           //so that you can return just Man.IsHittable
            return !(Man is RichMan);
        }
    }
}
```

You need only a `Person` reference in your class since you're taking in only a single person in the constructor. You can still throw exception there in the constructor if it warrants.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! In the real code, the nearest base of `RichMan` and `TaxiDriver` is `Object`, so use `Person` and `Object` is same for me. Your other answers is very helpful, thank you again

Comment: @Byzod but you say in the question that the nearest base for `RichMan` and `TaxiDriver` is `Person`. So why not use `Person` instead of `object`?

Comment: @Byzod that was confusing then to add in your question :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is appropriate to create a hierarchy of Person and a subclass per each ManType. That would allow you to get rid of some dependencies in the ManYouCanHit class which are manifested as conditionals.

What I mean is instead of that code:

```
  public ManYouCanHit(Person someone)
    {
        if(someone is RichMan)
        {
            this.richMan = someone;
            this.type = ManType.Rich;
        }
        else if(someone is TaxiDriver)
        {
            this.driver = someone;
            this.type = ManType.TaxiDriver;
        }
        else
        {
            // throw an error
        }
    }
```

you would get smth like this:

```
public void ManYouCanHit(Person someone)
  {
        someone.CanHit();
  }
```

This makes your life easier when adding new type of person or modifying behaviour for a concrete person

Comment: Thanks, it's a good idea. That were what I want to. Sorry for the miss information, _I can only access the instance_ means they're predefined classes, it's impossible to change them, and the language the real code is using don't support extension method.